# Yii2: how to control which attributes a user is allowed to see?

Tags: php, model, yii2, attributes, yii2-model

I'm wondering what the best approach is to control which model attributes a given user is allowed to **view**.

To control which attributes they are allowed to **modify** I'm of course using [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios), but sometimes they should be allowed to view attributes which they are not allowed to modify, so I can't just use the same list of attributes.

I want to control it at a central point, so preferably within the model I would guess.

What is the best way, or Yii intended method, to approach this?

Comment: have a look at [fields](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#fields()-detail) method. it nicely filters out any fields you want to hide in a [rest-api context](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-fields) however in other use cases (grids forms) you'll have to pretty much manage it manually

Comment: @csminb Not sure how I would use that since that only seems to be only for `toArray`. Feel free to post an answer with example.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that I needed something similar to [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios) so, building on that idea I have now tried to make a solution where I create a method called `viewable` on my model, which returns a list of attributes that should be visible for the current scenario of the model. For example:

```php
public function viewable() {
    $scenario = $this->getScenario();

    if ($scenario == self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT) {
        return [];

    } elseif ($scenario == self::SCENARIO_EV_ADMIN) {
        return $this->attributes();  //admin is allowed to see all attributes on the model

    } elseif ($scenario == self::SCENARIO_EV_ORGANIZER_INSERT || $scenario == self::SCENARIO_EV_ORGANIZER_UPDATE) {
        $attributes = $this->activeAttributes();  //use list of attributes they can edit as the basis for attributes they can view
        array_push($attributes, 'ev_approved', 'ev_status');  //add a few more they are allowed to view
        return $attributes;

    } else {
        return [];

    }
}
```

Then eg. in `GridView` or `DetailView` I pass the list of columns/attributes through a helper that will filter out any attributes that were not returned by `viewable`. Eg.:

```
    'attributes' => MyHelper::filterAttributes([
        'eventID',
        [
            'attribute' => 'organizerID',
            'value' => \app\models\Organizer::findOne($model->organizerID)['org_name'],
        ],
        'ev_name',
        ....
    ], $model->viewable()),
```

My helper method being like this:

```
public static function filterAttributes($all_attributes, $attributes_to_keep) {
    $output = [];
    foreach ($all_attributes as $value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $colon = strpos($value, ':');
            if ($colon === false) {
                $name = $value;
            } else {
                $name = substr($value, 0, $colon);
            }
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            if ($value['attribute']) {
                $name = $value['attribute'];
            } elseif ($value['class']) {
                // always leave special entries intact (eg. class=yii\grid\ActionColumn)
                $output[] = $value;
                continue;
            } else {
                new UserException('Attributes name not found when filtering attributes.');
            }
        } else {
            new UserException('Invalid value for filtering attributes.');
        }

        if (in_array($name, $attributes_to_keep)) {
            $output[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

And in create.php/update.php (or _form.php actually) I do this:

```
$editAttribs = $model->activeAttributes();
$viewAttribs = $model->viewable();

....

if (in_array('organizerID', $viewAttribs)) {
    echo $form->field($model, 'organizerID')->textInput(['disabled' => !in_array('organizerID', $editAttribs) ]);
}

....
```

Feedback is welcome!